# How to change custom panel text in bigcommerce store?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have login with Bigcommerce control panel and try this for manage custom panel under bigcommerce store --

```
Go to 'Design' then open 'Design Mode' double click the text and you can change it.
```

but no there is no way to change the text under this.

Answer (score 0):

I think with the design mode, you can change the layouts. But, it does not seem to work intuitively for texts. If you are looking to change the display text - You should be able to change stuff like store name under settings -> store.

If you think about it - the category names, products, etc come from your inventory data, from your DB. If you want to edit the product names, or something like that, you need to work with your store data and edit stuff from your control panel.

Hope this helps! cheers.